# Проблема с заданием на ограничение ввода информации

Tags: python

**Задание 1**
*Условие:* Необходимо ввести 10 чисел с клавиатуры, после чего получаем на экран сумму всех введенных чисел.

Я сделал это задание, но, ограничение по сумме срабатывает тогда, когда программа видит 0 в значении. А мне по заданию надо чтобы ограничение сработало на десятое значение и высчитало сумму.

**Например:**
*Enter numbers (up to 10 values inclusive):*
Ввожу 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 и после того как ввёл 10 (как 10 значение), и нажал Enter, оно мне выдало *Sum: 55*

Либо же

Ввожу 3 9 2 15 2 3 8 9 6 5 и после того как ввёл 5 (как 10 значение), и нажал Enter, оно мне выдало *Sum: 62*

Надеюсь я суть донёс, что я хочу чтобы получилось.

**Моя "неправильная" версия**:

```
var0_1 = 0 # Sum
print('Enter numbers (up to 10 values inclusive):')
while True:
    var0_2 = int(input())
    if var0_2 == 0:
        break
    else:
        var0_1 += var0_2
print('Sum: ', var0_1)
```

**Итог**
Сумма прекращается когда в input поступает значение 0. А надо чтобы сумма прекращалась на вводе десятого значения, при этом, цифра может быть любой. Ограничений на числа нет.

**P.S.**
Не судите если вопрос действительно лёгкий, или я слишком глуп. Хотелось бы с объяснением пусть и небольшим + исправление решения. Новичёк в этом всём, по тихому разбираюсь не спеша. Спасибо за понимание, надеюсь поможете.

Comment: Вам же нужно проверять не введенное значение, а количество этих значений. То есть, вам нужен счетчик, который в цикле while вы будете увеличивать на 1 при каждом вводе. и проверять не равенство значения нулю а равенство счетчика десяти.

Comment: Проблема в том, что я и не понимаю как этот счётчик написать. Может Вы бы смогли мне с этим помочь?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем виде можно сделать так:

```
var0_1 = 0 # Sum
counter = 0 # инициализируем наш счетчик
print('Enter numbers (up to 10 values inclusive):')
while counter < 10: # проверяем, что счетчик вводов не больше 10
                    # (счетчик начинается с 0)
    var0_1 += int(input())  # сразу прибавляем ввод к сумме
    counter+=1              # увеличиваем значение счетчика
    
print('Sum: ', var0_1)
```

Comment: Да, и в правду так. Получилось то, что требовалось.
Спасибо большое за помощь!